# Uploading and retrieving image and video url in ASP.NET MVC4 Internet Application

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following model in my MVC 4 Internet Application

```
public class EventModel
{
    public int EventId { get; set;}
    public string EventTitle { get; set;}
    public string ImageUrl { get; set;}
    public string VideoUrl { get;set}
}
```

Here's the Create.cshtml code for the Image and Video

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model =>model.ImageUrl)
</div>
<div>
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.ImageUrl)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.ImageUrl)
</div>

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(model =>model.VideoUrl)
</div>
<div>
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.VideoUrl)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>Video.ImageUrl)
</div>

}
```

This is my controller code for the post method on create

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(EventModel eventmodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _db.EventModels.Add(eventmodel);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(eventmodel);
        }
```

How can I make the create page display buttons to upload image from the users computer. How do i modify my controller action to store the paths on the database and then how do I retrieve the image on the index.cshtml page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file uploading try this:

In controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EventModel eventmodel, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{ 
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
      var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Photo/"), filename);
      file.SaveAs(path);
      tyre.Url = filename;

      _db.EventModels.AddObject(eventmodel);
      _db.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(eventmodel);
}
```

And View:

```
<div>
   Image
   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
   @Html.HiddenFor( model => model.ImageUrl)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor( model => model.Url )
</div>
```