# How to upload and save file in database using mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my code for upload a file. It upload the file and save into upload folder. Now want to save the file name in the database. what can i do to save the file name in database.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(upload mRegister)
    {
        //Check server side validation using data annotation
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //TO:DO
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(mRegister.file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), fileName);
            mRegister.file.SaveAs(path);
            ViewBag.Message = "File has been uploaded successfully";
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you look for http://stackoverflow.com/a/17873972/1534785